# How can I `brew prune` multiple entries?

Tags: terminal, homebrew

After many calls with the Apple support, they told me I should reinstall the OS and restore my stuff with the migration assistant. I did it and almost everything works fine so far.

Only `brew doctor` shows me a few errors. I could fix the most of them by myself. I just don't know the most elegant way to solve the following error:

```
localhost:~ Newton1$ brew doctor
Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with "brew prune":
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/xylubt12.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/xylubt11.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/xylubt10.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/xyluat12.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/xyluat11.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/xyluat10.pfb
  .
  .
  .
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/blex.pfb
  /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/subdirs.el
  /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/autotest-mode.elc
  /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/autotest-mode.el
  /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/autoconf-mode.elc
  /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/autoconf-mode.el
  /usr/local/share/emacs/24.3
  /usr/local/share/applications/emacs.desktop
  /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current
  /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
  /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Resources
  /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Python
  /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers
```

I think now you know what I mean. And there are much more entries.

So, how I can fix it as easily as possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just run `brew prune` — this fixes them all in one go.

Run `brew prune -v` for verbose to see what it's doing.